# exist exceptions in app.use(express.static('public', options))?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I worked in Express in Node.js specifically with app.use (express.static ('public', options));

exist exceptions in this function?

For example:

ignore .jpg files in public?

PD: i know this its possible ignore dotfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), no.

What could do is just not serve a directory that has jpg files in it, or write your own middleware that handles it.